# layeradd event does not fire for geojson layers

Tags: leaflet, geojson

I'm trying to execute function after layer is added to map, this code does not work as expected.

```
var l = new L.GeoJSON(data);
l.on('layeradd', function(e) {
    console.log('layeradd', e);
});
map.addLayer(l);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're trying to get a layer add event of the GeoJSON layer, you should do `.on('layeradd'` on the map object, rather than the `l` object. If you want `layeradd` events *within* the GeoJSON layer, bind the layeradd event but add the data later - initialize as `new L.GeoJSON()`, then bind the event, then `l.addData(data)`.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone wants to do this with react-leaflet, I was not able to listen to `layeradd` on the map as suggested by @tmcw. However, listening to `add` on the layer worked:

```
<GeoJSON data={jsonContent}
  eventHandlers={{
    add: (e) => e.target._map.fitBounds(e.target.getBounds())
  }} 
/>
```